# Need sql query to obtain the following result

Tags: sql

I need help to obtain following  results:

**Table A**

```
A_ID     A_No
-------------
1        40
2        41
3        42
4        43
5        44
```

**Table B**

```
B_ID  A_ID   B_Type
--------------------    
1      2     70
2      2     70
3      2     60
4      2     50
5      2     70
6      4     40
7      4     60
```

I need to obtain the following result

```
A_No  B_Type (Maximum no)
---------------------------
41    70
43    60
```

Thank you

Comment: join the two tables, then you just need `group by` and `max`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming A_ID and A_No are both unique, if not you would have to include A_ID in the GROUP BY clause, but if you don't include it in the SELECT you could have possible duplicates, which may not be what you want?

```
Select A_No, MAX(B_Type) as B_Type
From tableA a join tableB b on a.A_Id = b.A_Id
Group by a.A_No
```

Does that work?